# Rotating Layout View and Labels in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-9.3, layouts

I have a question if you are able to, upon rotating the map, is there a way to do the same with the labels? If so, how?

Also, besides using the "Rotate Data Frame" to rotate the Layout View, which other method can you do to rotate the layout? I right-click but the rotate options are ghosted, meaning those options are non-clickable.

I have ArcView 9.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have an **AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe** program in your ArcGIS installation directory in the "Utilities" folder. See the "Rotate labels with data frame rotation" option:

[image]

Comment: Depends where ArcGIS is installed. Mine is in `C:\ARCGIS\Utilities`, but other's might have this in `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Utilities`

Comment: I have it up..I clicked the ROTATE LABELS WITH DF ROTATION.  I reopened arcview and tried the rotating, but same thing happened.  The labels would not rotate.  

what am I missing?

Comment: In order to apply settings you need to close ArcGIS, change setting in AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe, click Apply, then re-open ArcGIS.

Comment: did that already, three seperate times.  It's gotta be something simple. I'll try rebooting.

Comment: figured it out.. as I said, something simple that I was overlooking. toolbar - layer then click the rotation.. simple. 

Thanks Mike as I learned something new!